# How to stop cron from sending email when there is nothing in STDOUT or STDERR?

Tags: 14.04, cron, perl

Ubuntu 14.04lts with Perl 5.18.2.

This is a special case where Google did not help me. I do not want to turn off email  for all cron jobs, I have about 15 jobs in my crontab. I need to see the emails cron sends me if there are errors.

This one job is a special case for which I need a solution. I have a bash script in my crontab which calls a perl script which is setup to check for email every 5 minutes. (It is not possible for me to setup a full MTA.) If there is no email the script does not output anything to STDOUT or STDERR yet cron still sends me a blank email with the full path of the bash script in the subject.

1. I want cron and the Perl script to send me email if the perl script finds email and processes it, including if there are errors.
2. I don't want cron to send me a blank email if there is no output from the Perl script because no email was found. The script runs every 5 minutes.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Confirmed. It was a stray newline that was my problem. Problem solved. Cron does not send an email if there is no output. Thank you! Your comment helped.

Comment: `cron` doesn't send mails on no output. Are you sure it is printing nothing to stderr/out? Not even blank lines or whitespace?

Comment: I'm testing this right now. I found a newline and removed it. So far, no emails. I couldn't see the newline in alpine, my email reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a stray newline causing the blank email every 5 minutes.

Cron only sends an email if the cron job/program run has output. My output was a newline, which of course, I couldn't see in Alpine, but it was there. I found the newline that my program was printing and removed it.

Now I design my cron programs to never output anything unless it gets past the parameter checking.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? As it stands this answer is going to be deleted soon because it's too vague.

Comment: @DavidFoerster actually, it looks like that's all there is. `cron` doesn't send emails if there's no output, but if there's any output at all, even a blank line, it will send emails. Removing the superfluous newline was all that was necessary, it seems.